# IIS Rewrite: redirect with one of the query string parameters as part or the URL

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

What I would like to do is if I have link:

```
http://www.test.com/photo.asp?hash=hfz6rhfgz&offset=10
```

to rewrite as:

```
http://www.test.com/photo/hfz6rhfgz/?offset=10
```

There can be other query parameters and hash may be on some other place than the first...

The problem is it would work, but as offset is the second parameter with my rule I get:

```
http://www.test.com/photo/hfz6rhfgz/&offset=10
```

That of course causes an error as I would need `?` instead of `&`. In the redirected URL the offset is like second parameter and in the original link it is the second.

Here is my redirect rule:

```
<rule name="test-redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^photo.asp$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^(.*)hash=([\w]{8})(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/photo/{C:2}/{C:1}{C:3}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of find a solution by myself, but if there is something like

http://www.test.com/photo.asp?test=10&hash=jcekg876

It produces:

http://www.test.com/photo/jcekg876/?test=10&

so the last amp is too much, in other situations it works ok. If anybody knows how to get rid of this & it would be nice, because I need a clean URL redirect...

```
                <rule name="test-redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^photo.asp$" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)hash=([\w]{16})[&amp;]?(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/photo/{C:2}/?{C:1}{C:3}" redirectType="Found" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```